# Eclipse Swing to JavaC?

Tags: java

I made a program using Eclipse, but I want to learn to compile it with JavaC.

I downloaded the JavaSDK jdk1.7.0 and installed it at C:\

My .java file is in C:\java

I then compiled the program using C:\jdk1.7.0\bin\javac Game.java

It uses a package layout manager so I downloaded swing-layout-1.0.1.jar and just put it straight into C:\ then tried to execute using:

```
java -classpath C:\swing-layout-1.0.1.jar Game
```

All I get is Error:Could not find or load main class Game

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, simply for ease of usage and convenience, add your JDKs bin folder to your classpath, or create a JAVA_HOME environment variable to hold that path and then add it to your PATH.

Comment: do you have manifest file inside the jar?

Comment: try `java -classpath c:\swing-layout-1.0.1.jar;. Game` - your current directory is missing from your classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add your code to classpath. You should provide either jar file or directory where your classes are located, i.e.

`java -classpath C:\swing-layout-1.0.1.jar;myapp.jar Game`

or

`java -classpath C:\swing-layout-1.0.1.jar;c:\proj\myapp\classes Game`

Comment: Thanks, I am now getting it going, but its saying <wrong name: layout/Game> is this to do with the file structure?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of your main class you can try

```
java -classpath .;C:\swing-layout-1.0.1.jar; your.package.MainClass
```